# iphone game development, Cocos2d or OpenGL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am a programmer new in iphone development. 
I want to make a game for iPhone. 
I am confused which is better for development of games, OpenGl or Cocos2d, and what is difference between these two?

Thanks

Comment: Cocos2d IS OpenGL behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL is programming "at the metal".  Cocos2d is, effectively, a wrapper around OpenGL (and other technologies) that provides a higher level API.   Cocos2d is more than that;  there are also physics engines and other higher level tools available, too (there are the same available for OpenGL, too, really, but they are lower level, typically).

Personally, I would lean strongly to Cocos2d.  There are some fantastic high level tutorials available and it is, in my experience, much easier to use than raw OpenGL.

If you are worried about performance, consider that the game that shipped will always outperform the game that is still in development....

---

Ray Wenderlich's weblog has a  *long* series of articles on programming with cocos2d.  It is pretty awesome stuff.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial

Comment: thanks... if you have link of any beginning game(cocos2d) tutorial..please give. thanks again